# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I update 2 data, the first data is in the normal table, the second data uses EAV, therefore I have to use where to update the data that has the input ID

What im doing wrong..im getting this error..

this my controller

this is normal table

```
$vendor = Vendor::find($request->id);
$vendor->is_active = '0';
$vendor->name = $request->name;
$vendor->address = $request->address;
$vendor->save();
```

this is EAV Table

```
$values = [
    'detail'  => $request->detail,
    'join_at' => Carbon::now(),
];
VendorDetail::whereIn('vendor_id', $request->id)->update($values);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When using `whereIn()` in second argument you must be pass array

```
VendorDetail::whereIn('vendor_id', [$request->id])->update($values);
```

But in your case you can use

```
VendorDetail::where('vendor_id',$request->id)->update($values);
```

Comment: It looks like I definitely jumped the gun :)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in select query while using Eloquent. So posting my solution also. As already mentioned in other answers,

> When using whereIn() in the second argument you **must be**  array

My error was that I was using "=" as the second parameter and actual array as 3rd parameter. Removing the equal sign parameter like below resolved my issue.

```
$innerQuery->whereIn('wo.wm_is_completed', $completedFlagArr);
```